# Why is my variable undefined in my Jasmine test - Jasmine.js

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have started writing tests for my `js` files and I am getting an `undefined` where I don't expect it.  Here is my code:

```
describe('show jasmine testing', function() {
  var x;
  beforeEach(function() {
    x = 3;
  });

  describe('booleans', function() {
    it('should return true', function() {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  });

  describe('ints', function() {
    console.log('This is x: ' + x);
    expect(x).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

In my `ints` tests, my `x` variable is `undefined`, so the test always fails.  From what I understand it should be `3` because the `beforeEach` block is run before each `describe` block.  What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the spec inside an `it` block. `beforeEach` is run for each spec. By the time the describe has run, your `beforeEach` has yet to be executed.